# Добавить в таблицу excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

Есть две таблицы excel. Ссылка: transfiles.ru/f24p8

Соединила и записала:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_columns = 120


df_a = pd.read_excel('Пример выгрузки из 1С.xlsx', sheet_name='акты', skiprows=3)
df_c = df_a.drop(df_a.index[[6]])
df_b = pd.read_excel('АнализПодр.xlsx', sheet_name='Данные', skiprows=1)
res = pd.concat([df_b, df_c.rename(columns={'Дата': 'Дата Акта', 'Сумма': 'Сумма Акта', 'Контрагент': 'Контрагент', 'Договор': 'Договор'})], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
res.to_excel('temp.xlsx')
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли вариант дозаписи одной таблицы в другую? Т.е. добавить данные из второй таблицы в первую. Заранее благодарна за ответ.
Желаемый результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы можете уточнить вопрос? Покажите как должен  выглядеть результат? Говоря о таблицах вы имеете в виду DataFame’s или таблицы Excel ? По каким столбцам связаны таблицы? PS я доберусь до компьютера не раньше вечера или следующего утра , поэтому раньше ответить не смогу...

Comment: @MaxU, добавила желаемый результат в вопрос. Таблицы связаны по столбцам: 'Дата': 'Дата Акта', 'Сумма': 'Сумма Акта', 'Контрагент': 'Контрагент', 'Договор': 'Договор'. Буду ждать

Comment: Можете выложить примеры исходных таблиц на какой-нибудь файлообменник? Данные о клиентах и счетах лучше предварительно анонимизировать;)

Comment: @MaxU, ссылка на таблицы: http://transfiles.ru/f24p8

Comment: а зачем пандас?
используйте функцию =ВПР()  в экселе.

Comment: @Vasyl Kolomiets, я бы с удовольствием, но начальство просит, чтобы через python осуществлялась дозапись в файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [функцией `append_df_to_excel()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38075046):

```
t2 = pd.read_excel(r'D:\download\Таблица2.xlsx', skiprows=3)

append_df_to_excel('D:\download\Таблица1.xlsx', t2, sheet_name='Лист1')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import win32com.client
Excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb_receiver = Excel.Workbooks.Open(u'd:\\Users\\temp\\Таблица1.xlsx')
wb_source = Excel.Workbooks.Open(u'd:\\Users\\temp\\Таблица2.xlsx')

sheet_r = wb_receiver.Worksheets(1)
sheet_s = wb_source.Worksheets(1)

# количество строк в таблице
PosStr_r = sheet_r.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
PosStr_s = sheet_s.Cells(4, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
for i in range(1, PosStr_s+1):
    for j in range(1, 5):
        sheet_r.Cells(PosStr_r+i,j+3).value = sheet_s.Cells(4+i,j).value 


wb_receiver.Save()
wb_source.Save()
wb_receiver.Close()
wb_source.Close()
Excel.Quit()
```

Вариант для Windows. Книги подключаются как COM объект и внутри можно хоть VBA использовать.

Comment: супер!!! Всё работает!!! Спасибо!!!